# Nested async & await in Web API application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

I want to build asynchronous Web API using .NET Core

If I have async `Task` that's awaiting for a result from the service as below

```
        [HttpGet("User/")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser()
        {
            var result = await _service.GetUser();
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Now in `_service.GetUser` we do more than one task such as querying the database more than once.

So my question is do we have to use async & await as well in `_service.GetUser`, or is it enough that the caller method do? I'm kind of confused.

```
    public async Task<UserResponseDTO> GetUser(UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO)
    {
        var userId =  await _utilities.getUserId(); //shall we use it?
        var user = await _dbContext.getFullUserInfo //shall we use it?
           .Where(P => P.userId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
   

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRequestDTO.email))
        {
            var emailExists = await _dbContext.getFullUserInfo.Where(p => 
             p.Email == userRequestDTO.email).AnyAsync();  //shall we use it?
        }
    
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<UserResponseDTO>(user);
    }
```

Comment: You should do async/await all the way from the top to the bottom of the methods you are calling, so it is correct to make `GetUser` async and await the async calls in it.  Although I don't think you need the `SaveChangesAsync` as it does not appear that you actually change anything.

Comment: How would you implement that method *without* using `await`?  Obviously it's *possible* (asynchronous programming was done before `await` was even added to the language) but `await` was specifically added because it's much easier than the alternative.  If you just removed the `await` keyword and did nothing else then of course the whole thing wouldn't even compile, so you need to do *something*.

Comment: Imagine this was the case and the need to use `await` inside a routine depended on the caller of the routine. How can you know *if* your caller is using it? And even if you did somehow know that, *both* awaiting a task immediately and storing it to be awaited later are valid techniques, how would you distinguish between them?

Comment: @juharr Thanks for the reply . Actually SaveChangesAsync() is needed but I had to remove some of the code for simplicity

Comment: @Servy I was doing await in GetUser for one call to db. Then as my calls to db increase I felt there's somthing odd to repeat await for each

Comment: @Jack If you think that it's odd to do this, what do you think you should be doing instead?

Comment: @Servy Honestly I'm not sure what is the alternatives and that's why I reached out to you

Comment: @Jack If you don't even know how to write the code without `await`, then you probably shouldn't write the code without `await`.

Comment: @Servy I know how to write the code without await but I wanted to make the code asynchronous  as I said in the question.

Comment: @Jack I was trying to say that if you don't know how to write the code *so that it is still asynchronous* without using `await`, then you should just be using await.  I wasn't saying that you should change it to behave synchronously.  Writing code without `await` that's still asynchronous is possible, but much harder in all but the most trivial of situations.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to build asynchronous Web API Using .NET Core

Why?

There are a number of incorrect answers to that question; the most common one is probably "to make it faster". "To make it more scalable" I would say is only semi-correct.

The correct answer is "I have asynchronous work do to", where "asynchronous" in this context is roughly the same as "I/O-bound".

In your example code, you want an asynchronous Web API call *because* that call queries/updates the database.

> So my question is do we have to use async & await as well in _service.GetUser or is it enough that the caller method do?

Once you have the correct reasoning around "why", the solution is clearer. Specifically, you want to have asynchronous database methods *first*, and then make your API method asynchronous if it calls them.

Generally, it's best to start at the lowest-level calls and make those use `await`. `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, `AnyAsync`, `SaveChangesAsync`, etc. Anything doing I/O can be changed to use `await`. Once `GetUser` is an asynchronous method (and should be called `GetUserAsync`), *then* make your `GetUser` action method use `async`/`await`.